# Drag-Drop , Reorderabale layouts in android

Tags: android, android-layout, drag-and-drop

Story module like [MyAlbum iOS App](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/myalbum-visual-storytelling/id922005321?mt=8) replicating for android.

Features are like : 
1. Drag and Drop containers with image/text/video.
2. Reordering of containers with text/image/video views. 
3. Making dynamic containers by placing left,right,top,bottom places by dragging views.

So i tried with android with onDragListener , OnTouchListener .

Making containers basically took Viewgroups like linearlayout as main container as root with vertical orientation , and sublayouts linearlayout with horrizontal orientation by dynamically generating for views to get swapped or dragged to different dynamic containers(into linearlayouts) .

Problem is to make new linear layout above if drag view pointed to top layout that cannot be generated new layout at the same place.

Here are the other issues :

1. stack trace is very limited on phones may be less than 10Mb
2. Issues if views are more than 80 on run time , if uploaded a lot images and video views.

Can anyone suggest me about the structure and how to solve the view stack trace issues ?

whether canvas would be better option for this ??

Any Android experts in gesture can help me . I can share code with them as well.

Comment: On the iOS store page the closest preview image I can find that matches your question description is this [grid of images](http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple60/v4/9f/5f/3f/9f5f3fe6-f43d-d93f-81fb-1b4e12cd02c3/screen696x696.jpeg). Is this what you are attempting to replicate, with the ability to drag and re-order items?

Comment: Its a dynamic containers or you can say grid of images/text/video or views in any order . Row can hold 1...2..3..etc and rows can be created dynamically as well.

Comment: I would use a `RecyclerView`, with either `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` or `GridLayoutManager`, multiple view types and an `ItemTouchHelper`. This would allow for a grid of different sized containers containing different items. The containers could be dragged and dropped, and new containers inserted/removed dynamically.

Comment: What about if i want to push views to one container to another container ?

Comment: containers can be inserted at top or between or bottom .. not everytime bottom or updated only

Comment: one more question , is there a way to manage gesture for these items .